# Omniauth Steam with Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-7, rails7

I am creating a new application with **rails 7**. I would like to add a way for the user to signup via steam. I used the code which works on **rails 6**, but on **rails 7** I receive an **error**.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.ax.theKeyIamHidingforStackOverflow' 
(redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/auth/Steam') 
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by 
CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control 
check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the 
request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Clicking on the `https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?fooBar` I get to stream and also redirected to my app and I am signed in.
I tried to set cors in `config/initializers/cors.rb` like:

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'https://steamcommunity.com'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post]
  end
end
```

But this does not work. Do I need to allow the visit of third party websites before I try to redirect to them?

Did something change on rails 7 to protect redirect?

This is the post to the server

```
= form_tag '/auth/Steam', method: :post do
  = submit_tag 'Steam'
```

Best Regards

Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this, we need to disable turbo on making an Ajax request by using the form like this:

```
= form_tag '/auth/steam', method: :post, data: { turbo: false } do
  = submit_tag 'Steam'
```

This Form contains `data: { turbo: false }` which disables `turbo`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).